# Objeto.begin() en Arduino no inicia

Tags: c++, arduino

No he conseguido que el objeto se incie. La temperatura leida es siempre -127 grados y esto es asi cuando el sensor no esta conectado o esta mal configurado.

Alguno podria decirme donde estoy fallando ?

Esta es la definicion de la clase en el archivo cabecera .h

```
#ifndef SENSORTEMERATURA_H
#define SENSORTEMERATURA_H
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

class SensorTemperatura {

public:

  SensorTemperatura();
  SensorTemperatura(int);
  float leoTemperatura();
  OneWire nuestroCable; // pin como bus OneWire
  DallasTemperature sensorTemperatura; // variable u objeto para nuestro sensor


private:

  float temperatura;
  float temperaturaMaxima;
  int pinSensor;

};

#endif  // SENSORTEMERATURA_H
```

Esta es la implementacion de la clase en el archivo cpp.

```
#include "SensorTemperatura.h"

SensorTemperatura::SensorTemperatura(int pinSensor){
  this -> pinSensor = pinSensor;
  OneWire nuestroCable(pinSensor); // pin como bus OneWire
  DallasTemperature sensorTemperatura (&nuestroCable); // variable u objeto para nuestro sensor
  sensorTemperatura.begin();
}

float SensorTemperatura::leoTemperatura () {
  sensorTemperatura.requestTemperatures();   // Se envía el comando para leer la temperatura
  float temperatura = sensorTemperatura.getTempCByIndex(0); // Se obtiene la temperatura en ºC
  return(temperatura);
}
```

Y aqui esta el main.cpp

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "SensorTemperatura.h"

SensorTemperatura miSensor(8);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  miSensor.begin();

}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(miSensor.leoTemperatura());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando mal tus variables. Dentro del constructor, estás intentando inicializar tus variables-miembro `nuestroCable` y `sensorTemperatura`. Sin embargo, tal y como lo estás haciendo, en realidad lo que haces es **crear variables nuevas** con el mismo nombre ... que *ocultan* a tus variables-miembro.

Has de usar la [lista de inicialización](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) para lo que pretendes:

```
SensorTemperatura::SensorTemperatura( int pinsensor ) :
    nuestroCable( pinsensor ),
    sensorTemperatura( &nuestroCable ),
    pinSensor( pinsensor )
{
    sensorTemperatura.begin( );
}
```

Adacionalmente, observa que el orden dentro de la lista de inicialización ha de coincidir con el orden en el que declaras las variables.

Comment: Ok, declaro las variables y luego cuando las uso me encuentro con el siguiente error: _no match for call to '(OneWire) (int&)'_ _no match for call to '(DallasTemperature) (OneWire*)'_

Comment: Releyendo el planteo que me persento @Trauma, pude resolverlo.
Queda por estudiar lista de inicializacion.